# Perform a segue by clicking a button in a custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to understand what is the correct way to perform a segue by clicking a button in a custom UICollectionViewCell (I'm using a storyboard to create the screens of the app).

I have a view controller which holds a UICollectionView:

```
    MyDataSource myDataSource = new MyDataSource(listOfItems);      
    myCollectionView.Source = myDataSource;
```

MyDataSource is a subclass of UICollectionViewSource

```
     public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
     {
            MyCustomCell customListCell = (MyCustomCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("listCell", indexPath);
            customListCell.updateItem(indexPath.Row);
            return customListCell;
     }
```

MyCustomCell updateItem method updates the cell's properties and also wires  TouchUpInside event for the button:

```
    public void updateItem(int index)
    { 
         myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
         {
            /* NOW I WANT TO PERFORM THE SEGUE 
               AND PASS THE INDEX THAT WAS CLICKED */
         };  
    }
```

After reading some old questions a few solutions were suggested, which I'm trying to avoid:

1. Pass a reference to the parent ViewController and use this reference to perform the segue.
2. Create a segue in the storyboard and when the user clicks the button save a static value of the selection which can be accessed from the next ViewController.

Seems to me that these two solutions are more of a workaround and using Events is the correct path, but I'm not sure regarding the implementation.

So for example I will create an EventHandler in MyCustomCell:

```
public event EventHandler<MyDataType> ButtonClicked;
```

Then in TouchUpInside:

```
    myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
    {
             ButtonClicked(this, MyDataType);
    };
```

But for this to work I will need to use this event in the parent view controller:

```
   MyCustomCell.ButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
   {
                PerformSegue("theSegueIdentifier", this);
   };
```

I don't have any reference to MyCustomCell in the parent view controller,
so how can I use this event in the parent view controller?

Comment: I need a slightly better understanding of VC hierarchy. You have a Parent (it contains the collectionView?) and the childVC (assuming this one has it) will performa segue to a 3rd VC (or back to the parent segue?) but you also you need to run a function on the parentVC?

Comment: There is one VC that contains the collection view. When the user clicks the button in the custom cell of this collectionView I want to perform a segue that will navigate to another VC.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

**VC:**

`MyDataSource myDataSource = new MyDataSource(listOfItems,CurrentVC);`

**DataSource:**

```
this.currentVC = CurrentVC;

myButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
{

     currentVC.PerformSegue("theSegueIdentifier", this);
     //currentVC is the instance of current controller  
};
```

**Better** recommend to try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios-multiscreen/hello-ios-multiscreen-deepdive) to navigation ,then not need to create Segue 
related to Button for each cell:

```
NextViewController nextController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("NextViewController") as NextViewController ;
if (nextController != null) {     
     this.NavigationController.PushViewController (nextController, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another EventHandler "buttonClicked2" in your datasource class "MyDataSource", and do this:

```
MyCustomCell.ButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
{
            //PerformSegue("theSegueIdentifier", this);
            //instead of perform segue, you raise the event
            buttonClicked2();
};
```

Then you can fill in the rest.